# Loopback remote method not returning response body

Tags: loopbackjs

So I created this remote method in loopback:

```
Message.findUserMessages = function(id,cb) {

        Message.find({ 
            where: { 
                from_user_id: id 
            },
            include: {
                "relation":"message_text"
            }

        });
    };

    Message.remoteMethod('findUserMessages', {
        accepts: {
            arg: 'id',
            type: 'number'
        },
        returns: {
            arg: 'response',
            type: 'Object'
        },
        http: {
            path: '/user/',
            verb: 'get'
        }
    });
```

But when I view the response, it does not show the output in the response body. The only reason I know the correct results are being accessed is due to the fact that my DB is returning the result of the query. How do I get put the output of the query in the response body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should be:

```
Message.findUserMessages = function(id, cb) {
    Message.find({ 
        where: { 
            from_user_id: id 
        },
        include: {
            "relation":"message_text"
        }
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cb(null, response);
    });
};

Message.remoteMethod('findUserMessages', {
    accepts: {
        arg: 'id',
        type: 'number',
        required: true,
        http: { source: 'path' }
    },
    returns: {
        arg: 'response',
        type: 'Object',
        root: true
    },
    http: {
        path: '/user/:id/findUserMessages',
        verb: 'get'
    }
});
```

You forget to callback the response.

**Note:** I've also changed the http url path hoping you wanted it like so. And also source to the argument is set to `path`. You might also want to look at usage of `root`.